# HAML: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Getting the above error (the line number listed as the error is after the end of the file)

```
%H1= 'Week '+@week
-@days.each |day| #do
  %H2= 'Day '+day
  %table{:id => "day_#{day}"}
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Back Squat (reps)
        %th %1RM
        %th Weight 
        %th Front Squat (reps)
        %th %1RM
        %th Weight 
    %tbody
      -@workout[day].each |set| #do
        %tr
          %td= set.first.reps
          %td= 100 * set.first.percentage 
          %td= set.first.percentage * @bs_1rm
          -unless set.last.nil? 
            %td= set.last.reps
            %td= 100 * set.last.percentage 
            %td= set.last.percentage * @fs_1rm
          -else
            %td/
            %td/
            %td/
```

Any ideas?  In HAML it's normally an indentation issue but I'm not seeing it...

Comment: Are you sure the capitalized headers are OK? I never did that, I'd use 'h1', I'd also align those `%td` inside the `unless` and `else` with those from the `tr`. Also, what are those `%1RM`? I can't remember where but I read that it is not a good practice to use `unless` with `else`, if you read that in English, it makes no sense, the "correct" way is to use `if` and `else`

Comment: Lowercased the headers and replaced the %1RM with another name in case it mattered.  No dice.  You can't unindent the conditionals block or it won't parse.  Tried it anyway but it no longer understands the `if`/`else` at all, as expected.

Comment: So my tip is, remove parts of the code until you isolate where the problem really is, also try replacing the variables with texts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
-@days.each |day| #do
```

Should be:

```
- @days.each do |day|
```

With haml you don't `end` a block, but you have to open it with `do`

Comment: Thanks! Right after I read it, I thought "of course, all the blocks open but don't close in HAML" Turns out there were other bugs but that's the one that broke the parser.